# Model not getting values from POST request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to POST something to my Web API but not matter what I do the model values are always set to null.

I have tried the following request (trace copied from fiddler):

```
POST http://localhost:53176/api/Profile HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:53176
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 40
Accept: application/xml, text/xml, */*; q=0.01
Origin: http://localhost:53176
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Referer: http://localhost:53176/SignUp
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=do5ddqwghl3v0bhlgr3pyicb

{"InputEmail":"aa","UserName":"asd"}
```

**Update**
and also with the following:

```
POST http://localhost:53176/api/Profile HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:53176
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 44
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Origin: http://localhost:53176
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json
Referer: http://localhost:53176/SignUp
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=do5ddqwghl3v0bhlgr3pyicb

{"InputEmail":"asdas","UserName":"dasd"}
```

My api looks like:

```
    //here I have also tried [FromBody]
    public MyDto Post(MyDto input)
    {
       return input;
    }
```

MyDto has two properties and is:

```
public class MyDto 
{
    string InputEmail { get; set; }
    string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

Would someone be able to tell me what is the problem in this code or if there is anything that I am missing?

I would also like to know how (or where) can I put the debugger somewhere inside webapi code to see what was the actual request before the webapi tries to deserialize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Content-Type` header is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, but your body has json data. Modify your content-type header to be either `application/json` or `text/json`

**EDIT**:
Make your properties `Public`

Comment: no it does not work with it as well. I have edited the question with the new request.

Comment: if possible can you tell me how can I put the debugger somewhere inside webapi code to see what was the actual request before it tries to deserialize it.

Comment: thanks, wasted my night trying to see what is happening with the request. Just implemented a custom http handler and also tried Json object instead of a model which apparently had all the values in it BUT could not see that my model has private members arghh...

Comment: Thanks a lot once again :)